# conditional vectors, read ing the output

Tags: r

```
x <- c(11,5,9,6,31,32,27,28,40,10,25,7)
y <- c(10,29,6,22,16,20,39,18,36,17,32,15)
z <- (x<y) | (x<=10)


"z[c(9,4)]" gives me: "FALSE  TRUE".
```

Can you explain me how to read this code?

Answer (score 0):

If we check one by one:

```
> (x<y)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> (x<=10)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

OR condition "|" gives TRUE if any one of the comparision is TRUE. So Z looks like this:

```
> z
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Here the 9th position is FALSE because both (x<y) and (x<=10) are false at corresponding positions, similarly for index position 4, both are TRUE, hence you get FALSE, TRUE for `z[c(9,4)]`

Comment: Thank you very much!!